# Enable hot reload inside a package inside flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Building a flutter project where its structure like this

```
app/
   lib/
      packages/
              my_package
```

when i import the package inside my app pubspec.yaml like this:

```
  my_package:
    path: "lib/packages/my_package"
```

and then import it and use it, when the app is running and i make a modifications inside this package, the app will not responds to these modifications until I stop the app and re-run it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the next in VS Code:

1. Create a parent folder for the main project and the packages

```markdown
- parent_folder
   - main_project
   - packages
      - package_1
      - package_2
```

2. In the parent folder create a file `.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "project_name",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "cwd": "main_project",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
        }
    ]
}
```

And with this when you save a change on your package, you main project will be loaded with it

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it now doing what expected from it